# SQL Server 2008 - Best way to handle public and private records on the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, private, public

I have a table of records on my database which has about a million records. Most of the records are public - meaning all the users on the system are able to view them. However on the same exact table, I have private records as well, usually couple of hundreds for each user. I have about 1K users on the system.

Each record has 3 main columns:

- `ID` - Enum of the record ID. Unique primary key.
- `UserID` - Identifies the record owner. Null = General record available to everyone. ID = Private record available only for this specific user ID.
- `RecID` - Public record ID. Unique for all public records. If a public record is changed by a user, the system duplicates this record with a new ID, but the same `RecID`.

Example

```
ID  RecID   UserID  Comments
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   1000    NULL    General record
2   1000    1   Modification of record ID=1, available only for userID=1
3   1001    NULL    General Record
4   1002    NULL    General Record
5   1001    2   Modification of record ID=3, available only for userID=2
```

- If User 1 logs into the system, he should get the list of records 2,3,4
- If User 2 logs into the system, he should get the list of records 1,4,5
- If user 3 logs into the system, he should get the list of records 1,3,4

The query I'm using is as follow:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TB_Records
WHERE UserID = @UserID 
   OR (RecID IS NULL AND NOT RecID IN (SELECT RecID 
                                       FROM TB_Records 
                                       WHERE UserID = @UserID)
```

The problem I'm having is performance. Adding on top of this query sorting filtering and paging results with a performance of 5-10 seconds for each select. When removing the 3rd line of the query - selecting all the records, the performance is much better, 1-2 seconds.

I would like to know if there is a better way to handle such a requirement.

Thanks

Comment: Have you got an unclustered index on the UserID?  If you added one, it would improve performance.  There are other solutions, but that's the first question to be asked.

Answer (score 1):

This query doesn't make sense.  The `AND NOT` part is unnecessary, because a `NULL` value of `RecID` would not do what you expect.  I think you mean:

```
SELECT r.* 
FROM TB_Records r
WHERE r.UserID = @UserID OR
      (r.UserId IS NULL AND NOT r.RecID IN (SELECT r2.RecID 
                                            FROM TB_Records r2
                                            WHERE r2.UserID = @UserID)
```

First, create indexes on `TB_Records(UserId, RecId)`.  That might help.  Next, I would try changing this to an explicit `left outer join`:

```
select r.*
from TB_Records r left outer join
     TB_Records r2
     on r2.UserId = @UserId and
        r2.RecId = r.RecId
where r.UserId = @UserId or r2.RecId is NULL;
```

EDIT:

One more attempt, with a different approach.  This uses a window function to see if the user is present for a given record:

```
select r.*
from (select r.*,
             max(case when r.UserId = @UserId then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by RecId) as HasUser
      from TB_Records r
     ) t
where r.UserId = @UserId or HasUser = 0;
```

Otherwise, you should put the execution plans in the question.  Sometimes, it a query with `union all` will optimize better than one with `or`:

```
select r.*
from TB_Records r
where r.UserId = @UserId
union all
select r.*
from TB_Records r left outer join
     TB_Records r2
     on r2.UserId = @UserId and
        r2.RecId = r.RecId
where r2.RecId is NULL;
```

Comment: Hello. Tried that on my full query and the performance is the same. Any other idea to make it run faster ?